# How do I make a div appear, then slide all the way to the right, then fade out slowly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates

How would I do that in JQuery?

Comment: Have you looked into the jQuery `.animate()`? Is there a reason why you want **us** to code it for you?

Comment: I can't figure out how to do queue up animations

Comment: Call each subsequent animation in the complete callback function of .animate(). E.g. `$('.myclass').animate({prop: 0}, function(){$this.animate(...)});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your element a `position:absolute` and give this a try, it might be off a few pixels (padding and borders).

```
var elm = $('#YourElmID');
var maxLeft = $('body').width() - elm.width();
elm.fadeIn();
elm.animate({left: maxLeft}, 2000, function(){
    elm.fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

1. [**jQuery Show();**](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
2. [**jQuery Animate();**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
3. [**jQuery FadeOut();**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Here is an quick shot which would do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/LGBUJ/

Did you know that [jQuerys chaining](http://ejohn.org/blog/ultra-chaining-with-jquery/) is really great?!

Answer (score 0):

"animate()" has a "complete" option. You supply a function that you want to run once the animate has completed. So, for the first animate (appear), you have a complete function that does another animate (slide-right). That animate has as its complete function another animate (fade out slowly).

In this way each one starts when the previous completes.

Regards
       Neil